# How do I display the growth in sales month on month as a percentage in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to display the growth in sales month on month, I've gotten the growth in sales for each sale that has taken place but I'm struggling to group them by month.

My table is called OrderDetails and my columns are order_date and Selling_cost.

Any help would be great! The code I'm using is:

```
with x as (

select MONTH(order_date), selling_cost,

lag(selling_cost) over(order by month(order_date)) as prev_payment

from OrderDetails

)

select *, (selling_cost/prev_payment)-1 as Growth

from x
```

Comment: So basically based on total display % per month?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can build on your attempt. You can aggregate in a CTÉ, the compute the percent increase in the main query:

```
with x as (
    select 
        year(order_date) yr,
        month(order_date) mh,
        sum(selling_cost) sales 
    from OrderDetails
    group by yr, mh 
)
select
    x.*,
    (sales - lag(sales) over(order by yr, mh)) / sales * 100 sales_increase_percent
from x
```

Note: you want to group by month *and* year; eventually, your data will spread over years...

Comment: thank you! This did exactly what I needed, much appreciated!